# Getting Forbidden Error in Microsoft ToDo Tasks create subscription Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-todo

When creating subscription using Graph API, we are getting the below error even if we have enough permission in access token.

Token permissions: `Calendars.ReadWrite Contacts.ReadWrite Tasks.ReadWrite User.Read profile openid email`

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Access is denied to the requested resource. The user might not have enough permission.]",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2022-11-30T08:23:03",
        "request-id": "0541655d-83f3-456e-af47-165caf259c76",
        "client-request-id": "0541655d-83f3-456e-af47-165caf259c76"
    }
  }
}
```

Details used:

Request url :

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
```

Request body:

```
{
    "notificationUrl":"<development-url>/notifications/office365/graph/v1",
    "expirationDateTime":"2022-12-03T06:48:06Z",
    "resource":"/me/todo/lists/{taskListId}/tasks",
    "changeType":"created,updated,deleted",
    "clientState":"<client-state>"
}
```

API used - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions ([Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http))

**Issue affected users count - 190**

Comment: Could you confirm that all 190 affected users have Tasks.ReadWrite?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) to create the subscription for todoTask , User must have Tasks.ReadWrite deligated permission ,its not supported for application permission , could you please check what permission you have ?

[image]

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: Hi ,

Thanks for your answer.

We are using delegated permissions only.

Comment: Thanks for the update , all user having same delegated permissions?

Comment: Yes, all user have same delegated permissions

Comment: Thanks for the update ,give me some time to research , i will get back to you , thanks

Comment: Hi @karthik ,Sorry for delay ,unable to figure out the root cause of the issue , could you please again , let us know if you are still facing the same issue , thanks.